# Initiate Specific version of IE browser by giving path in Selenium Webdriver Script

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have written a script in selenium webdriver to initiate IE browser by default installed with windows.
I have mentioned IEdriver.exe file in script also to initiate the IE browser.

Requirement:-
Want to given broswer.exe path of specific location as I have IE9,IE10 and IE11 installed in my machine using some software.

Problem:- Not able to initiate different version of browsers using the same script.

Kindly let me know if any one has solution of above problem.

Thanks,
Sahil

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use different version of IE (IE6, 7, 8, 9 and 10) in Selenium WebDriver with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375956/how-to-use-different-version-of-ie-ie6-7-8-9-and-10-in-selenium-webdriver-w)