# Run selenium for ie8 verison through nightwatch

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-8, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run my tests for ie8 , as we know selenium webriver supports this,Im using nightwatch.js as framework and specifying the ie 8 version in configruation json file

```
"ie" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "version": "8",
        "acceptSslCerts": true

      }
    }
```

But it runs with my OS default IE 11's version

Comment: Doesn't selenium use the version of IE installed on the box?

Comment: It uses my computer's IE deafult version in my case its 11 , but Im setting it to with config to 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375956/how-to-use-different-version-of-ie-ie6-7-8-9-and-10-in-selenium-webdriver-w

Comment: oh I missed this answer, Thank you !